# Django dj-rest-auth registration

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm using dj-rest-auth registration, which enables to override register serializer and that's what I'm trying to do. Unfortunately I don't know how I am supposed to do that given my models:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):

    username = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField('date joined', default=timezone.now)
    year = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    university = models.ForeignKey(University, related_name='students', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class RegisterSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    username = serializers.CharField(
       max_length=40,
       min_length=3,
       required=True
    )
    email = serializers.EmailField(required=True)
    password1 = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)
    password2 = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)
    year = serializers.IntegerField(required=True, write_only=True)


    def validate_username(self, username):
       username = get_adapter().clean_username(username)
       return username

    def validate_email(self, email):
        email = get_adapter().clean_email(email)
        if allauth_settings.UNIQUE_EMAIL:
            if email and email_address_exists(email):
                raise serializers.ValidationError(
                    "A user is already registered with this e-mail address."
                )
        return email

    def validate_password1(self, password):
        return get_adapter().clean_password(password)

    def validate(self, data):
        if data['password1'] != data['password2']:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("The two password fields didn't match.")
        return data

    def custom_signup(self, request, user):
        user.year = self.validated_data.get('year', '')
        user.university = University.objects.filter(name=self.validated_data.get('university', ''))
        user.save(update_fields=['year'])

    def get_cleaned_data(self):
        return {
            'username': self.validated_data.get('username', ''),
            'password1': self.validated_data.get('password1', ''),
            'email': self.validated_data.get('email', ''),
            'year': self.validated_data.get('year', '')
        }

    def save(self, request):
        adapter = get_adapter()
        user = adapter.new_user(request)
        self.cleaned_data = self.get_cleaned_data()
        adapter.save_user(request, user, self)
        self.custom_signup(request, user)
        setup_user_email(request, user, [])

        return user
```

My question is how to add my university foreign key to a register serializer, to enable me to send post request with some university?